# I'm facing issues with Data Preparation while using Netflix Data

Tags: python, deep-learning, recommendation-engine, netflix

I'm facing issues with Data Preparation while using Netflix Data. I just cloned a repo from Github and I'm facing issues while trying to run the code in Jupyter Notebook.

```
%%time

%run ./DeepRecommender/data_utils/netflix_data_convert.py $NF_PRIZE_DATASET $NF_DATA

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Major Project\Code\RS\DeepRecommender\data_utils\netflix_data_convert.py in <module>
    184 
    185 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 186     main(sys.argv)
    187 

D:\Major Project\Code\RS\DeepRecommender\data_utils\netflix_data_convert.py in main(args)
     93 
     94   text_files = [path.join(folder, f)
---> 95                 for f in listdir(folder)
     96                 if path.isfile(path.join(folder, f)) and ('.txt' in f)]
     97 

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/datadrive\\netflix\\download\\training_set'

Wall time: 162 ms
```

Can someone help me out?

I'm using Windows 10 Home. This code is made to work on Ubuntu, is this problem occurring just because I'm using Windows?

If you need any other details, let me know.

I have added the code which is in `[netflix_data_convert.py][2]`.

```
    # Copyright (c) 2017 NVIDIA Corporation
from os import listdir, path, makedirs
import random
import sys
import time
import datetime

def print_stats(data):
  total_ratings = 0
  print("STATS")
  for user in data:
    total_ratings += len(data[user])
  print("Total Ratings: {}".format(total_ratings))
  print("Total User count: {}".format(len(data.keys())))

def save_data_to_file(data, filename):
  with open(filename, 'w') as out:
    for userId in data:
      for record in data[userId]:
        out.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(userId, record[0], record[1]))

def create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                  train_min,
                                  train_max,
                                  test_min,
                                  test_max):
  """
  Creates time-based split of NETFLIX data into train, and (validation, test)
  :param all_data:
  :param train_min:
  :param train_max:
  :param test_min:
  :param test_max:
  :return:
  """
  train_min_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(train_min,"%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
  train_max_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(train_max, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
  test_min_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(test_min, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
  test_max_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(test_max, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())

  training_data = dict()
  validation_data = dict()
  test_data = dict()

  train_set_items = set()

  for userId, userRatings in all_data.items():
    time_sorted_ratings = sorted(userRatings, key=lambda x: x[2])  # sort by timestamp
    for rating_item in time_sorted_ratings:
      if rating_item[2] >= train_min_ts and rating_item[2] <= train_max_ts:
        if not userId in training_data:
          training_data[userId] = []
        training_data[userId].append(rating_item)
        train_set_items.add(rating_item[0]) # keep track of items from training set
      elif rating_item[2] >= test_min_ts and rating_item[2] <= test_max_ts:
        if not userId in training_data: # only include users seen in the training set
          continue
        p = random.random()
        if p <=0.5:
          if not userId in validation_data:
            validation_data[userId] = []
          validation_data[userId].append(rating_item)
        else:
          if not userId in test_data:
            test_data[userId] = []
          test_data[userId].append(rating_item)

  # remove items not not seen in training set
  for userId, userRatings in test_data.items():
    test_data[userId] = [rating for rating in userRatings if rating[0] in train_set_items]
  for userId, userRatings in validation_data.items():
    validation_data[userId] = [rating for rating in userRatings if rating[0] in train_set_items]

  return training_data, validation_data, test_data


def main(args):
  # create necessary folders:
  for output_dir in [
    "Netflix/N3M_TRAIN", "Netflix/N3M_VALID", "Netflix/N3M_TEST", "Netflix/N6M_TRAIN",
    "Netflix/N6M_VALID", "Netflix/N6M_TEST", "Netflix/N1Y_TRAIN", "Netflix/N1Y_VALID",
    "Netflix/N1Y_TEST", "Netflix/NF_TRAIN", "Netflix/NF_VALID", "Netflix/NF_TEST"]:
    makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

  user2id_map = dict()
  item2id_map = dict()
  userId = 0
  itemId = 0
  all_data = dict()

  folder = args[1]
  out_folder = args[2]

  text_files = [path.join(folder, f)
                for f in listdir(folder)
                if path.isfile(path.join(folder, f)) and ('.txt' in f)]

  for text_file in text_files:
    with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
      print("Processing: {}".format(text_file))
      lines = f.readlines()
      item = int(lines[0][:-2]) # remove newline and :
      if not item in item2id_map:
        item2id_map[item] = itemId
        itemId += 1

      for rating in lines[1:]:
        parts = rating.strip().split(",")
        user = int(parts[0])
        if not user in user2id_map:
          user2id_map[user] = userId
          userId += 1
        rating = float(parts[1])
        ts = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(parts[2],"%Y-%m-%d").timetuple()))
        if user2id_map[user] not in all_data:
          all_data[user2id_map[user]] = []
        all_data[user2id_map[user]].append((item2id_map[item], rating, ts))

  print("STATS FOR ALL INPUT DATA")
  print_stats(all_data)

  # Netflix full
  (nf_train, nf_valid, nf_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                "1999-12-01",
                                                                "2005-11-30",
                                                                "2005-12-01",
                                                                "2005-12-31")
  print("Netflix full train")
  print_stats(nf_train)
  save_data_to_file(nf_train, out_folder + "/NF_TRAIN/nf.train.txt")
  print("Netflix full valid")
  print_stats(nf_valid)
  save_data_to_file(nf_valid, out_folder + "/NF_VALID/nf.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix full test")
  print_stats(nf_test)
  save_data_to_file(nf_test, out_folder + "/NF_TEST/nf.test.txt")


  (n3m_train, n3m_valid, n3m_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                   "2005-09-01",
                                                                   "2005-11-30",
                                                                   "2005-12-01",
                                                                   "2005-12-31")
  print("Netflix 3m train")
  print_stats(n3m_train)
  save_data_to_file(n3m_train, out_folder+"/N3M_TRAIN/n3m.train.txt")
  print("Netflix 3m valid")
  print_stats(n3m_valid)
  save_data_to_file(n3m_valid, out_folder + "/N3M_VALID/n3m.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix 3m test")
  print_stats(n3m_test)
  save_data_to_file(n3m_test, out_folder + "/N3M_TEST/n3m.test.txt")

  (n6m_train, n6m_valid, n6m_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                   "2005-06-01",
                                                                   "2005-11-30",
                                                                   "2005-12-01",
                                                                   "2005-12-31")
  print("Netflix 6m train")
  print_stats(n6m_train)
  save_data_to_file(n6m_train, out_folder+"/N6M_TRAIN/n6m.train.txt")
  print("Netflix 6m valid")
  print_stats(n6m_valid)
  save_data_to_file(n6m_valid, out_folder + "/N6M_VALID/n6m.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix 6m test")
  print_stats(n6m_test)
  save_data_to_file(n6m_test, out_folder + "/N6M_TEST/n6m.test.txt")

  # Netflix 1 year
  (n1y_train, n1y_valid, n1y_test) = create_NETFLIX_data_timesplit(all_data,
                                                                   "2004-06-01",
                                                                   "2005-05-31",
                                                                   "2005-06-01",
                                                                   "2005-06-30")
  print("Netflix 1y train")
  print_stats(n1y_train)
  save_data_to_file(n1y_train, out_folder + "/N1Y_TRAIN/n1y.train.txt")
  print("Netflix 1y valid")
  print_stats(n1y_valid)
  save_data_to_file(n1y_valid, out_folder + "/N1Y_VALID/n1y.valid.txt")
  print("Netflix 1y test")
  print_stats(n1y_test)
  save_data_to_file(n1y_test, out_folder + "/N1Y_TEST/n1y.test.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. Copy them into your post and format them appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked fine.

Actually, I replaced `$NF_PRIZE_DATASET` with `training_set` (this is the folder under the root directory of `DeepRecommender` folder, `training_set` contains the dataset which I got from [Netflix Dataset](https://academictorrents.com/details/9b13183dc4d60676b773c9e2cd6de5e5542cee9a)) and `$NF_DATA` with `NF_DATA`

```
%%time
%run ./DeepRecommender/data_utils/netflix_data_convert.py training_set NF_DATA
```